# Heating element for Air Conditioner thermostat

Tags: heat, thermostat

I currently have a series of thermostats that are connected to a window air conditioner, one is used to check room temperature the other is to trick the AC to run to a lower temperature by switching on/off a heating element connected (taped to) to the AC thermostat.
The heating element that I am using is a night light bulb, which works fine except they are no longer making them (except for LEDs which don't put out enough heat) and they last about 2 or 4 months.
I found on eBay "12V-220V Constant Temperature PTC Heater Element Thermostat Heating Plate Tablet" which is rated to heat to about 200C at 110V.

> Voltage: AC DC 12V          12V dry burning table temperature: 80℃ / 120℃ / 220℃ ± 10 ° C

Voltage: AC DC 24V          24V dry burning table temperature: 70℃ / 110℃ / 220℃ ± 10 ° C

Voltage: AC DC 36V          36V dry burning table temperature: 220℃ ± 10 ° C

Voltage: AC DC 48V          48V dry burning table temperature: 220℃ ± 10 ° C

Voltage: AC DC 110V        110V dry burning table temperature: 230℃ ± 10℃

I only need a temperature of about 40 degrees C /100F, so is there some way I can wire in one of the thermostats with a resistor/transformer, etc. or something?
I don't want to melt everything!
Thanks?

Comment: Why on Earth are you doing this to your air conditioner and its thermostat?

Comment: Why not just use a programmable thermostat which is much more accurate and much more flexible?

Comment: I made something which makes an AC unit cool below the regular minimum temperature of about 65F and will go to 40/45F without freezing up.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily substitute a power resistor for your light bulb. Just pick the resistance so that it will dissipate the same number of watts. Remember that power(watts) = Volts^2 / resistance(ohms).